# Recovering a ring from its localization and completion with respect to a fixed element

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, localization, completion, pullback

Suppose I have a commutative ring $k$ and an element $x \in k$. Then I can form the localization $k[x^{-1}]$ of $k$ at the multiplicative subset $\{ 1, x, x^2, ... \}$, and I can form the completion $\hat{k}$ of $k$ with respect to the filtration $(x), (x^2), (x^3),...$. Under what conditions is the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
k @>>> k[x^{-1}] \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\hat{k} @>>> \hat{k}[x^{-1}]
\end{CD}$$
a pullback square?

The natural map from $k$ to the fiber product $\hat{k} \times_{\hat{k}[x^{-1}]} k[x^{-1}]$ is injective if and only if there are no elements of $k$ which are both infinitely $x$-divisible and $x$-power torsion. Is the natural map always surjective? Ideally, I don't want to assume $k$ is Noetherian, but I'm willing to if necessary. I'm not an algebraist, so apologies if this is well-known.

Comment: If $x$ is a non-zero divisor it is surjective. I don't know whether it is necessary.